# Contour Integral of $\sin(z)/(z^2-z)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Find the integral $\int_{\lambda}\frac{\sin(z)}{z(z-1)}$ where $\lambda(t) = 10e^{it},t\in[0,2\pi]$

We notice that there are poles at $z = 0$ and $z=1$.  So we can use residue theorem but I am confused as to how to handle the coefficient 10 in $10e^{it}$.

Comment: Your contour of integration is just a circle with radius ten, centered at the origin. It follows that both residues lie inside of the circle. Therefore: $I=2 \pi i (Res[z=0]+Res[z=1])$

Comment: okay so from there, I see that 0 is a removable discontinuity so the residue at 0 is 0 right? The residue at 1 is sin(1), I think.  So then the integral is just $2i\pi\sin(1)$?

Comment: i think you are right

Comment: @bobbyjones yes, it is a removable singularity and so does not contribute a residue

Answer (score 1):

The contour if integration is a circle of radius 10 centered at the origin. Both singularities at $z=0$ and $z=1$ lie inside the circle. The singularity at the origin is a removable singularity, as $\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(z)}{z}=1 $, so the residue is zero. The residue at $z=1$ is $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}(z-1)\frac{\sin(z)}{z(z-1)}=\frac{\sin(1)}{1}$. Therefore the integral is just $2i\pi\sin(1)$.